# How to stop advertisements being displayed to right of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has recently started displaying advertisements to right of main display :

[image]

Different advertisements appear when I open a new tab/window.

How do I stop these ? I've tried re-installing Chrome but did not work.

Comment: That dosen't look normal, and thats definately not google. Malware ahoy?

Comment: Looks like that's to the right, not the left.

Comment: @qqx ive edited

Comment: Can you click the ad and tell us how to earn $379 a day? :-P

Comment: @Magnetic_dud :) now its gone I want it back!! too late I geuss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you installed a rogue extension. Try disabling all of them by going to chrome://chrome/extensions/

I see you have Skype extension installed, so I guess one of these:

- you reinstalled it without uninstalling it first (hence keeping all the settings)
- The extensions are synced to your Google account and you got it back after the reinstall

Comment: yep, that seemed to work. I also had a 'yontoo' extension installed. I'm not sure what was causing it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some adware installed it for you. Nowadays there are a lot of "free" software that do like that if you are not very careful during the setup